# String input to categorical column via dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to learn how to use the `Estimator` API, using `input_fn` to provide `Dataset` backed input to a `feature_column` generated input layer.

My code looks like

```
import tensorflow as tf import random

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

def input_fn():
    def gen():
        for i in range(100000):
            for j in range(10):
                yield {"in": str(j)}, [str(j+1)]
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, ({"in": tf.string}, tf.string))
    data = data.batch(10)
    iterator = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
    return iterator.get_next()

vocabulary_feature_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key="in",
        vocabulary_list=map(lambda i: str(i), range(11)))

embedding_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
        categorical_column=vocabulary_feature_column,
        dimension=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(input_fn()))
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
            feature_columns = [embedding_column],
            hidden_units = [5,5],
            n_classes = 11,
            model_dir = '/tmp/predict/snap')

    classifier.train(
            input_fn=input_fn)
```

but running it I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 33, in 
    input_fn=input_fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 302, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 711, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 694, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 334, in _model_fn
    config=config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 190, in _dnn_model_fn
    logits = logit_fn(features=features, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 89, in dnn_logit_fn
    features=features, feature_columns=feature_columns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 230, in input_layer
    trainable=trainable)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 1837, in _get_dense_tensor
    inputs, weight_collections=weight_collections, trainable=trainable)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2123, in _get_sparse_tensors
    return _CategoricalColumn.IdWeightPair(inputs.get(self), None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 1533, in get
    transformed = column._transform_feature(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2091, in _transform_feature
    input_tensor = _to_sparse_input(inputs.get(self.key))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 1631, in _to_sparse_input
    raise ValueError('Undefined input_tensor shape.')
ValueError: Undefined input_tensor shape.
```

Looking at the tf sources I get the impression I that the categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list expects a tensor as output instead of a string, but I have a hard time understanding how to make my input_fn provide that the right way.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

As a comparison, the following code works perfectly fine: https://pastebin.com/28QUNAjA

**EDIT**

I noticed that replacing `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` makes the code run.

I.e. the following actually works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

def input_fn():
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"in": map(lambda i: str(i), range(10))}, range(1,11)))
    data = data.repeat(1000)
    data = data.batch(10)
    iterator = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
    return iterator.get_next()

vocabulary_feature_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key="in",
        vocabulary_list=map(lambda i: str(i), range(11)))

embedding_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
        categorical_column=vocabulary_feature_column,
        dimension=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(input_fn()))
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
            feature_columns = [embedding_column],
            hidden_units = [5,5],
            n_classes = 11,
            model_dir = '/usr/local/google/home/zond/tmp/predict/snap')

    classifier.train(
            input_fn=input_fn)
```

This ought to be a bug, so I created https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15178.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I noticed that using `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` instead of `from_generator` makes the code work, as in:

Comment: FeatureColumns expect the shape of the input tensors to be known but from_generator uses functions which erase the shape. from_tensor_slices should be preferred if it's at all possible to use it